# Basic Authentication of Squid - /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth file not found

Tags: centos, authentication, squid

I have centos 7.6 & installed squid 4.5 on it.

```
sudo yum -y install squid
```

I followed this [link](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-on-centos-7/) for `Basic Authentication`.
Without authentication squid works fine.
Here is squid.conf after adding `# Basic Authentication` part :

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
# http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# Basic Authentication
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Basic Authentication
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow auth_users

# allow all requests    
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow all

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Please see `# Basic Authentication` part.
The problem is :
 `/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth` file not exist.
Where is that file?
How can i fix this problem?

---

**- Edit after comment -**
Here is result for `yum info squid`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.softaculous.com
 * epel: mirror.wiuwiu.de
 * extras: mirror.alpix.eu
 * updates: centosmirror.netcup.net
Installed Packages
Name        : squid
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 7
Version     : 4.5
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 10 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : squid
Summary     : The Squid proxy caching server
URL         : http://www.squid-cache.org
License     : GPLv2+ and (LGPLv2+ and MIT and BSD and Public Domain)
Description : Squid is a high-performance proxy caching server for Web clients,
            : supporting FTP, gopher, and HTTP data objects. Unlike traditional
            : caching software, Squid handles all requests in a single,
            : non-blocking, I/O-driven process. Squid keeps meta data and especially
            : hot objects cached in RAM, caches DNS lookups, supports non-blocking
            : DNS lookups, and implements negative caching of failed requests.
            :
            : Squid consists of a main server program squid, a Domain Name System
            : lookup program (dnsserver), a program for retrieving FTP data
            : (ftpget), and some management and client tools.
```

Comment: That configuration is for the stock squid 3.5

Comment: I also saw this thread : https://serverfault.com/questions/358382/failed-to-run-squid-on-centos-5 > Not help

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro : What is the correct configuration for squid 4.5?

Comment: No idea. I know the location (and name) can change depending on version.

Comment: The version of the Squid package in the CentOS official repo is 3.5.20. And this package contains the 'basic_ncsa_auth' file at the specified location. Did you install another variant? What does `yum info squid` tell you?

Comment: Please see my edit : It's version 4.5. Without authentication every thing is ok.But i don't know what is the problem for basic authentication in squid 4.5 & where is that auth file!!!!

Comment: http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you aren't using the CentOS packaged squid, but the ones packaged [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#KnowledgeBase.2FCentOS.Squid-4_release).  It might have helped if you had mentioned that in your question.

If you look at the repo, it appears there is a squid-helpers package that includes `/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth`.

EDIT: if it wasn't clear, `yum install squid-helpers` would solve your problem.

Comment: What is basic_ncsa_auth.8? I found it in this path : /usr/share/man/man8/basic_ncsa_auth.8.gz

Comment: Its the man page.

Comment: Can i use this file?

Comment: No.  It is the documentation for the authentication plugin.  If you run `man basic_ncsa_auth`, that's the file it reads.  Just install the squid-helpers package if you want the file.  Also, maybe consider investing in some basic Linux training because man pages are pretty much day 1 of learning how to use Linux.

Comment: Man really really thanks. Problem solved. You are the best.

Comment: I was looking for `/usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth` on rhel7, but got the error `No such file or directory`. Thanks for pointing out the correct path!

Answer (score 1):

Centos changed the **path**:

You can use: `/usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth` or  `/usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth`

It's works fine!